# controller is not a function got undefined when defining controller in site provider

Tags: angularjs

This is my `app.js`

```
angular.module('data',['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider

    .state('home', {

    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/showusers.html',
    controller: 'Crud'


    })
    .state('about', {
    url: '/about',
    templateUrl: '/app/views/addusers.html',

    })


    });
```

CrudController.js

```
angular.module('values', []).controller('Crud', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    function edituser(id)
    {
    console.log(id);
    }
    });
```

This is `index` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>
        MEAN Stack App
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">

    </head>
    <body ng-app="data">
        <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

        <script src="/app/controller/CrudController.js"></script>
        <script src="/app/app.js"></script>

        <div class="container">
            <h1>MEAN Application</h1>
            <h1>xsx{{firstName}}</h1>

            <div ui-view>


            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

when I define controller in `app.js` in site provider, it returns controller is not a function got undefind.

I am using `angularjs1.5.8` version.Please help me out from this problem. I am new to this tech.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link both the `App.js` and `Controller`. In your service:

```
angular.module('values', ['controllerinject']) // => here you injected your controller


.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/app/views/showusers.html',
      controller: 'Crud'
    })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
})
```

And in your controller add same `angular.module('controllerinject', [])`